# How to use If condition for wordpress plugin Widget Logic

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to put an IF condition on a widget through the plugin Widget Logic.

if single post is 'this', then dispay this text.

I tried this but it doesn't work, do you know why ?

```
if ( is_single( 'dialyse-mayotte' ) ) {
   echo 'test'; // conditional content/code
}
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

is_single only checks if the page is single you should check if the page is this and is it a single page

`if ( is_page( 'dialyse-mayotte') && is_single() ) { echo "test"; }`

Comment: It's exactly the same code:

if ( is_page( 'dialyse-mayotte') && is_single() ) { echo "test"; }

( Using Widget Logic plugin )

Comment: want to see `Using Widget Logic plugin` part of code.

Comment: There is no other code...
Widget Logic plugin is installed, and the you put PHP code inside the widget itself.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-logic/other_notes/

Comment: Have you asked in plugin support forum, that might bring some help, as I do not think any thing wrong with our code after visiting the page url you have given.Only you can try using `is_page( 'page_id' )` and check if it is working.